# Как убрать прыгания при наведении на блок?

Tags: html, css

Верстаю тренировочный макет(на названия классов и id забил). Не могу решить проблему, когда при наведении все скачет, в том числе и фон. Убирал отступы, но решить не получилось. В чем проблема ?
P.S Не судите строго, я верстаю не так давно(

```css
.women_bags {
  border: 0px solid #F3F3F3;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 48px 3px rgba(237, 235, 253, 0.75);
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 20%;
  width: 95%;
}

.women_bags h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

.like {
  display: none;
  height: 18px;
  width: 20px;
  float: left;
  margin: 30px 10px 0px 30px;
  color: red;
}

.likes {
  display: none;
  float: left;
  padding: 15px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.comments {
  display: none;
  float: right;
  padding: 15px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.comment {
  display: none;
  height: 21px;
  width: 25px;
  float: right;
  margin: 30px 30px 0px 10px;
}

.women_bags #women_bag_1,
#women_bag_2,
#women_bag_3,
#women_bag_4,
#women_bag_5,
#women_bag_6 {
  width: 226px;
  height: 245px;
  padding: 0px 39px 0px 39px;
}

.women_bags div {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 505px;
  width: 330px;
  margin: 5%;
}

.info_bag {
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
}

.price {
  font-family: "Open Sans - Semibold";
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}

.buy_button {
  display: none;
  width: 129px;
  height: 48px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: "Open Sans - Semibold";
  font-size: 25px;
  box-shadow: -1px 5px 24px 1px rgba(240, 239, 254, 0.99);
  background-color: #fcfcfc;
  background-image: linear-gradient(26deg, #8c84f9 28%, #a165f4 50%);
  padding: 20px 40px 5px 40px;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 35px;
}

.women_bags div:hover {
  outline: 0px solid;
  box-shadow: -1px 5px 48px 3px rgba(221, 223, 224, 0.99);
}

.women_bags div:hover .price {
  color: #8c84f9;
  font-family: "Open Sans - Semibold";
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: 900;
}

.women_bag_1:hover .like,
.women_bag_2:hover .like,
.women_bag_3:hover .like,
.women_bag_4:hover .like,
.women_bag_5:hover .like,
.women_bag_6:hover .like {
  display: block;
}

.women_bag_1:hover .comment,
.women_bag_2:hover .comment,
.women_bag_3:hover .comment,
.women_bag_4:hover .comment,
.women_bag_5:hover .comment,
.women_bag_6:hover .comment {
  display: block;
}

.women_bag_1:hover .likes,
.women_bag_2:hover .likes,
.women_bag_3:hover .likes,
.women_bag_4:hover .likes,
.women_bag_5:hover .likes,
.women_bag_6:hover .likes {
  display: block;
}

.women_bag_1:hover .comments,
.women_bag_2:hover .comments,
.women_bag_3:hover .comments,
.women_bag_4:hover .comments,
.women_bag_5:hover .comments,
.women_bag_6:hover .comments {
  display: block;
}

.women_bag_1:hover .buy_button,
.women_bag_2:hover .buy_button,
.women_bag_3:hover .buy_button,
.women_bag_4:hover .buy_button,
.women_bag_5:hover .buy_button,
.women_bag_6:hover .buy_button {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="women_bags">
  <div class="women_bag_1">
    <img src="images/object_like.svg" alt="like" class="like">
    <p class="likes">253</p>
    <img src="images/object_comment.svg" alt="comment" class="comment">
    <p class="comments">120</p>
    <img src="images/women_bag_1.svg" alt="women_bag_1" id="women_bag_1">
    <p class="info_bag">Black Genuine Leather Bags</p>
    <p class="price">$ 23.20</p>
    <a href="" class="buy_button">Add to Cart</a>
  </div>
  <div class="women_bag_2">
    <img src="images/object_like.svg" alt="like" class="like">
    <p class="likes">65</p>
    <img src="images/object_comment.svg" alt="comment" class="comment">
    <p class="comments">180</p>
    <img src="images/women_bag_2.svg" alt="women_bag_2" id="women_bag_2">
    <p class="info_bag">Fashion Red Leather Bags</p>
    <p class="price">$ 20.16</p>
    <a href="" class="buy_button">Add to Cart</a>
  </div>
  <div class="women_bag_3">
    <img src="images/object_like.svg" alt="like" class="like">
    <p class="likes">143</p>
    <img src="images/object_comment.svg" alt="comment" class="comment">
    <p class="comments">15</p>
    <img src="images/women_bag_3.svg" alt="women_bag_3" id="women_bag_3">
    <p class="info_bag">Fashion Genuine Leather Bags</p>
    <p class="price">$ 30.14</p>
    <a href="" class="buy_button">Add to Cart</a>
  </div><br>
  <div class="women_bag_4">
    <img src="images/object_like.svg" alt="like" class="like">
    <p class="likes">333</p>
    <img src="images/object_comment.svg" alt="comment" class="comment">
    <p class="comments">155</p>
    <img src="images/women_bag_4.svg" alt="women_bag_4" id="women_bag_4">
    <p class="info_bag">Simply Leather Bags</p>
    <p class="price">$ 15.20</p>
    <a href="" class="buy_button">Add to Cart</a>
  </div>
  <div class="women_bag_5">
    <img src="images/object_like.svg" alt="like" class="like">
    <p class="likes">98</p>
    <img src="images/object_comment.svg" alt="comment" class="comment">
    <p class="comments">191</p>
    <img src="images/women_bag_5.svg" alt="women_bag_5" id="women_bag_5">
    <p class="info_bag">New Fashion Leather Bags</p>
    <p class="price">$ 25.20</p>
    <a href="" class="buy_button">Add to Cart</a>
  </div>
  <div class="women_bag_6">
    <img src="images/object_like.svg" alt="like" class="like">
    <p class="likes">508</p>
    <img src="images/object_comment.svg" alt="comment" class="comment">
    <p class="comments">311</p>
    <img src="images/women_bag_6.svg" alt="women_bag_6" id="women_bag_6">
    <p class="info_bag">Single Hand Models Bags</p>
    <p class="price">$ 17.6</p>
    <a href="" class="buy_button">Add to Cart</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Пересмотреть все стили с hover и найти который изменяет положение или размер элемента и сделать как вам угодно

Comment: а вы не display: none пишите а пишите opacity: 0

Comment: в стилях с hover я вообще не писал свойства размера

Comment: Если opacity: 0, то при наведении они показываться не будут

Comment: А вы в hover пишите opacity: 1; и всё будет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Много что изменил. Для исчезновения не используйте display:none;
Вам остаётся только цифры там изменить.

```css
.women_bags {
 margin-top: 50px;
 border: 0px solid #F3F3F3;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 48px 3px rgba(237, 235, 253, 0.75);
 width: 1000px;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.women_bags h2 {
 text-align: center;
}

.women_bag{
 display: inline-block;
 margin: auto;
 padding: 0px 20px;
 width: 300px;
 height: 520px;
}

.women_bag:hover {
 outline: 0px solid;
 box-shadow: -1px 5px 48px 3px rgba(221, 223, 224, 0.99);
}

.like {
 height: 18px;
 width: 20px;
 float: left;
 margin: 30px 0px 0px 0px;
 color: red;
}

.likes {
 float: left;
 padding: 15px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.comment {
 height: 21px;
   width: 25px;
   float: right;
   margin: 30px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.comments {
 float: right;
   padding: 15px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.status{
 width: 100%;
 height: 75px;
 opacity: 0;
}

.women_bag_img{
 width: 200px;
 height: 250px;
}

.info_bag {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 font-family: "Open Sans";
 font-size: 18px;
 text-align: center;
}

.price {
 font-family: "Open Sans - Semibold";
 font-size: 25px;
 text-align: center;
}

.buy_button {
 width: 120px;
 height: 25px;
 color: #ffffff;
 font-family: "Open Sans - Semibold";
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 25px;
 box-shadow: -1px 5px 24px 1px rgba(240, 239, 254, 0.99);
 background-color: #fcfcfc;
 background-image: linear-gradient(26deg, #8c84f9 28%, #a165f4 50%);
 padding: 15px;
 border-radius: 35px;
 opacity: 0;
}

.women_bag:hover .price {
 color: #8c84f9;
 font-family: "Open Sans - Semibold";
 font-weight: 900;
}

.women_bag:hover .status{
 opacity: 1;
}

.women_bag:hover .buy_button{
 opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <center>
  <div class="women_bags">
   <div class="women_bag">
    <div class="status">
     <img src="images/object_like.svg" class="like">
     <p class="likes">253</p>
     <p class="comments">120</p>
     <img src="images/object_comment.svg" class="comment">
    </div>
    <center>
     <img src="images/women_bag_1.svg" class="women_bag_img">
    </center>
    <p class="info_bag">Black Genuine Leather Bags</p>
    <p class="price">$ 23.20</p>
    <center>
     <a href="" class="buy_button">Add to Cart</a>
    </center>
   </div>
   <div class="women_bag">
    <div class="status">
     <img src="images/object_like.svg" class="like">
     <p class="likes">253</p>
     <p class="comments">120</p>
     <img src="images/object_comment.svg" class="comment">
    </div>
    <center>
     <img src="images/women_bag_1.svg" class="women_bag_img">
    </center>
    <p class="info_bag">Black Genuine Leather Bags</p>
    <p class="price">$ 23.20</p>
    <center>
     <a href="" class="buy_button">Add to Cart</a>
    </center>
   </div>
   <div class="women_bag">
    <div class="status">
     <img src="images/object_like.svg" class="like">
     <p class="likes">253</p>
     <p class="comments">120</p>
     <img src="images/object_comment.svg" class="comment">
    </div>
    <center>
     <img src="images/women_bag_1.svg" class="women_bag_img">
    </center>
    <p class="info_bag">Black Genuine Leather Bags</p>
    <p class="price">$ 23.20</p>
    <center>
     <a href="" class="buy_button">Add to Cart</a>
    </center>
   </div>
   <div class="women_bag">
    <div class="status">
     <img src="images/object_like.svg" class="like">
     <p class="likes">253</p>
     <p class="comments">120</p>
     <img src="images/object_comment.svg" class="comment">
    </div>
    <center>
     <img src="images/women_bag_1.svg" class="women_bag_img">
    </center>
    <p class="info_bag">Black Genuine Leather Bags</p>
    <p class="price">$ 23.20</p>
    <center>
     <a href="" class="buy_button">Add to Cart</a>
    </center>
   </div>
   <div class="women_bag">
    <div class="status">
     <img src="images/object_like.svg" class="like">
     <p class="likes">253</p>
     <p class="comments">120</p>
     <img src="images/object_comment.svg" class="comment">
    </div>
    <center>
     <img src="images/women_bag_1.svg" class="women_bag_img">
    </center>
    <p class="info_bag">Black Genuine Leather Bags</p>
    <p class="price">$ 23.20</p>
    <center>
     <a href="" class="buy_button">Add to Cart</a>
    </center>
   </div>
   <div class="women_bag">
    <div class="status">
     <img src="images/object_like.svg" class="like">
     <p class="likes">253</p>
     <p class="comments">120</p>
     <img src="images/object_comment.svg" class="comment">
    </div>
    <center>
     <img src="images/women_bag_1.svg" class="women_bag_img">
    </center>
    <p class="info_bag">Black Genuine Leather Bags</p>
    <p class="price">$ 23.20</p>
    <center>
     <a href="" class="buy_button">Add to Cart</a>
    </center>
   </div>
  </div>
 </center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо, чутка подкорректировал небольшие недочеты и все сошлось, спасибо еще раз огромное)